# member of a political party

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

Is there an expression that means a member of a political party, who 
often comments rashly in a way that contradicts the party line?

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Seeing some of the answers so far, I suppose it depends on what you're trying to convey - a *rebel* would frequently fail to support his party; a *maverick* would be independently-minded and thus do much the same; someone who *fails to toe the party line* wouldn't always do as he's told. All of those perhaps reflect voting patterns - but merely to comment sounds more clumsy, maybe less intentional. *Unguarded*, *inept*, *blundering*, or similar. You also have a simple *disloyal*. Can you perhaps clarify what you're trying to say, then?

Comment: I agree.. more context would help if you're looking for a particular word.

Comment: "Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase **must include information on how it will be used** in order to be answered. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: About single word requests"  In the absence of such info, I've voted to close.

Answer (score 3):

More context is needed to answer appropriately.  You could be referring to a presumptive nominee or a capitalist marauder, presidential election or cultural revolution...even the word "party" as in "politcal" needs more context here.  Parties have varying forms of power and behaviors depending on the political system under which they're functioning. Are you trying to compare Trump to Mao?  Probably not, but specificity is the only way to get your questioned really answered.

(I happen to like juicy open-ended questions because the ensuing dig for all possible answers always yields cool stuff.  BlackPast.org and "enfant terrible" - thank you for those!)

Anyway, I personally like **maverick** here, but depending on context, again, it may or may not be effective.  I think the use of the term **maverick** in past political campaigns has been contextualized in a way that Jean Berko Gleason, psycholinguistics researcher, calls "framing", so any usage post -McCain/Palin-ticket comes with a caveat.  I can't even think of the word without hearing echoes of other Palinisms like "you betcha"...but in answer to your question, this might help.

Here's a few more that might aren't repeats of the above

**iconoclast**

**deviant**

**heretic**

**renegade**

If you're interested in further reading, here ya go:

"Who You Callin' A Maverick?"
http://www.nytimes.com/2008/10/05/weekinreview/05schwartz.html?_r=0

"'Hopey-Changey' Alive"
http://www.nytimes.com/2011/06/19/weekinreview/19word.html

"Jean Berko Gleason on how words influence thought"
http://www.dailymaverick.co.za/article/2011-10-26-jean-berko-gleason-on-how-words-influence-thought/

p.s.  If you have a question that is quite broad, and don't necessarily have a clear understanding of the context, it would be helpful to know that too.  You could frame your question in a way that also asks for contextual/cultural relevance, and you could give specific examples of where you might have doubt or need clarification.

Answer (score 2):

You might call this person a [maverick](https://www.google.com/webhp?ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%3A%20maverick):

> an unorthodox or independent-minded person.
>
> "a maverick among Connecticut Republicans"
>
> synonyms: individualist, nonconformist, free spirit, unorthodox
>   person, original, eccentric; rebel, dissenter, dissident, enfant
>   terrible; cowboy, loose cannon, bad boy
>
> "he was the maverick in the family, the only one who valued freedom
>   over an inheritance"
>
> antonyms: conformist

If you wanted a word with a negative connotation, you could call the person a **rogue**.

Comment: In the US at least 'going rogue' does not always have a negative connotation.

Comment: @DJClayworth I agree with you, but I can't find a good reference that covers that connotation.

Comment: Sarah Palin calls her book 'Going Rogue'. I doubt she would do that if it had a negative connotation.

Comment: @DJClayworth I agree with you, but I can't find a good reference that covers that connotation.

Answer (score 1):

[***loose cannon***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/loose-cannon)

> : a person whose reckless behavior endangers the efforts or welfare of others. [1975–80]

[Random House](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/loose-cannon)

> (idiomatic, by extension) An uncontrolled or unpredictable person who
>   causes damage to their own faction, political party, etc. Jack is
>   considered a loose cannon due to his volatile personality and his
>   track record of being unable to maintain his composure

[Wiktionary loose cannon](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/loose_cannon)

***free electron***

> *One of the principal points of Taubira’s political program is the need for government to address the concerns of people of color, women, and others who have been excluded from the mainstream political systems. She has been called a “free electron” in politics because of her sometimes independent stances apart from party politics.*

[BlackPast.org](http://www.blackpast.org/gah/taubira-christiane-taubira-delannon-christiane-1952)

***live wire***

> A person who is energetic, impulsive, etc.

[Webster's New World College Dictionary](http://www.yourdictionary.com/live-wire)

Answer (score 0):

It largely depends on the context (*how* and/or *what* said candidate is contradicting).

For example, the current republican nominee of the United States is often described as a [political outsider](https://www.google.ca/#q=define+outsider):

> a person who does not belong to a particular group.

You might also have someone whose grassroots beliefs are much stronger than others affiliated with their party. Those people might be referred to as [extremists](https://www.google.ca/#q=define+extremist) or [reformists](https://www.google.ca/#q=define+reformist).

Contradicting the norms of the party can differ in a number of ways... therefore, there are many different descriptors that can be used.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get high-falutin you might call them [heterodox](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/heterodox), though this would tend to imply more of a thought-out, principled difference in beliefs between an individual and the group's doctrine, rather than implying rashness.